# How can one configure a JIRA key to start with something other than 1?

Tags: jira

For example, PROJ-123 as the first issue instead of PROJ-1.

I was able to do this once via a properties file but cannot seem to find it now.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault most likely

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Reset+Issue+Key+for+a+project) may help you out. It involves running an SQL statement against the Jira database.

Comment: Thank you, mopoke! There is a way however to outright start a project with the intended number. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! .. it can be done by modifying the project.pcounter field in the database.